# mysql_connect not working with php?

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

My code only shows a blank page with no text. Why could the `mysql_connect` not connect to the database?

I am using MySQL version is 5.0.77 and PHP version is 5.1.6

```
$user = "user";
$password = "user";
#$database = "database";

$con = mysql_connect("localhost",$user,$password);

if (!con) {
    echo "could not connect";
} else {
    echo "connected";
}

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE my_db",$con)) {
     echo "databse created";
}

#@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
#$query="CREATE TABLE tablename(id int(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,first varchar(15) NOT NULL,last varchar(15) NOT NULL,field1-name varchar(20) NOT NULL,field2-name varchar(20) NOT NULL,field3-name varchar(20) NOT NULL,field4-name varchar(30) NOT NULL,field5-name varchar(30) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id),UNIQUE id (id),KEY id_2 (id))";
#mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: are you sure username and password are correct .. since i think you are on local host and havnt change default so try `$user ="root"` and `$password=""`

Comment: I think it's a typo `if(!con)` should be `if(!$con)`.          `NOTE:` mysql_* function have been deprecated in PHP. Please update your code to use either mysqli_* of pdo_mysql http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, 
[here is a good tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893).

Answer (score 4):

Well i wold like to point out one by one

**1.** you are using !con which is invalid and [generate error](http://3v4l.org/T9AFe#v430)

> Notice: Use of undefined constant con - assumed 'con' in blabla on line bla
>   connected

to use like this you need to declare constant which i think you don't want so use

```
if(!$con){
```

---

**2.** The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189)

---

**3.** as i saw in comment you have not turned on error reporting you can do this by in php.ini file

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

---

**4.** do not use `#` for comment however its same as `//` comment and cause no problem till **5.5.0alpha3**  [**live result**](http://3v4l.org/9u9jb#v430) . however [its(`#`) deprecated Comments starting with '#' are now deprecated in .INI files.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php) so its better to use

1. For single line comment `// this is single line comment`
2. For multiline comment `/* this is multiline comment */`

Answer (score 2):

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
[Check here for detailed information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Answer (score 1):

First try Following code only

```
<?php
$user="user";
$password="user";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$user,$password);
if(!$con)
{
echo "could not connect" ;
}
else
{
echo "connected";
}
?>
```

Then see the result and update here

Comment: Add $con in condition @user1601000

Comment: Replace `if(!con)` by `if(!$con)` & check again

Comment: @Usman however its completely irrelevant to gave code of mysqli .. OP may not familiar with mysqli

Comment: there is not a big challenge in using mysqli in place of mysql @NullPointer i think...

Comment: the result is still the same... blank page... :(

Comment: how u save this file @user1601000

Comment: try to echo something before anything, because there might a problem with your php or sql configuration.

Comment: @user1601000  just use <?php echo "Hello";?>

Comment: @Wololo yeah.. its echoing what i have echoed before connecting

Comment: which operating system and server you are using??

Comment: that means your mysql database is not responding. Its still lagging somewhere, because your if statement must of landed to true or false and ultimately echo something.

Comment: its doing nothing on $con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$user,$password);

Comment: the code hangs on that statement $con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$user,$password);

Comment: have you restarted your mysql and apache server? try restarting

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysql_connect`.